# How to make efficient looping through a nested dictionary doing a minimization whitin the dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to minimize a function multiple times. I developed a class called `BlackScholesModel`; this class contains the function to be minimized which is the method `difference` from the `BlackScholesModel` class.

I created a nested dictionary to save each class object. The code of the nested dictionary is:

```
expirations = ('2020-12-17', '2021-12-16')
today = datetime.now()
stock_price = stockquotes.Stock("^GSPC").current_price

BSM = {name:name for name in expirations}

for i, a in enumerate(expirations):
    strikeP = {count:count for count in range(0,len(expirations))}
    for j in range(0,len(strike[a])):
        strikeP[j] = BlackScholesModel(datetime.strptime(expirations[i],"%Y-%m-%d"),\
                                       today,stock_price,strike[a][j],\
                                       premium=call_premium[a][j])
    BSM[a] = strikeP
```

Output:

```
{'2020-12-17': {0: <BlackScholesMerton.BlackScholesModel at 0x22deb7f5708>, 
                1: <BlackScholesMerton.BlackScholesModel at 0x22debc805c8>, 
                2: <BlackScholesMerton.BlackScholesModel at 0x22dec1312c8>},
 '2021-12-16': {0: <BlackScholesMerton.BlackScholesModel at 0x22debd324c8>,
                1: <BlackScholesMerton.BlackScholesModel at 0x22debd36088>,
                2: <BlackScholesMerton.BlackScholesModel at 0x22debd36fc8>,}}
```

Having this nested dictionary, I want to loop through each element and minimize each class method `difference`; however, the `len(BSM['2020-12-17'])` is 93 and the `len(BSM['2021-12-16'])` is 50. I have the following code:

```
implied_vol = {name:name for name in expirations}

x0 = 1

for i, a in enumerate(expirations):
    strikeP = {count:count for count in range(0,len(expirations))}
    for j in range(0,len(BSM[a])):
        strikeP[j] = minimize(BSM[a][j].difference,x0)['x']
    implied_vol[a] = strikeP
```

Due to the high volume of transactions, the computer cannot complete this operation. I am trying to find a way to make my code more efficient. I want to store each minimum result in a format similar to the nested dictionary `BSM`. Any help or thought is more than welcome.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, why use Pandas dataframes here?

Answer (score 0):

Mauricio

Have You tried to estimate the average execution time of the function `minimize(BlackScholesModel.difference, x0)` ? With that estimated number, is it possible to perform the number of minimizations you need ?

Assuming that is possible to perform this in a reasonable time, You can do it more quickly by parallelizing the execution:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def minimize_expiration(expiration_dict):
    strikeP = {}
    for i, bs in expiration_dict.items():
        strikeP[i] = minimize(bs.difference,x0)['x']
    return strikeP

N_JOBS = -1 # number of cores to use (-1 to use all available cores)
implied_vol_list = Parallel(n_jobs=N_JOBS, verbose=1)(delayed(minimize_expiration)(BSM[expiration]) for expiration in expirations)

IV = {expiration: iv for expiration, iv in zip(expirations, implied_vol_list)}
```

You may have issues with this approach if the implementation of BlackScholesModel is not serializable